# ApplicationOAuthProvider not found

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know which package I should install to fix this issue? I have already installed Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin

I'm getting: The type or namespace "ApplicationOAuthProvider" could not be found in my CorsApi

```
    namespace CorsApi
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        static Startup()
        {
            PublicClientId = "self";

            UserManagerFactory = () => new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
                Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),
                AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
        }

        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static Func<UserManager<IdentityUser>> UserManagerFactory { get; set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);

            // Enable CORS
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            // Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
            //app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
            //    clientId: "",
            //    clientSecret: "");

            //app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
            //    consumerKey: "",
            //    consumerSecret: "");

            //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
            //    appId: "",
            //    appSecret: "");

            //app.UseGoogleAuthentication();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to install corsAPI and I start getting this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case anyone had the same problem, they change the name of the class from "ApplicationOAuthProvider" to "OAuthAppProvider". Just use "OAuthAppProvider" :)